# Android : Get Activity/Fragment/Classes of different Apps with same user_id

Tags: android, android-fragments, plugins, fragment

First time asking on stackoverflow here !

Okay so here's the context. I'm doing an android application, and I'm trying to implement something like a plug-in framework.
My main app's MainActivity's purpose is to manage and launch/show Fragments.
Each of my plug-in will contain (at least) a Fragment and it's layout.
Thus, the idea is to fetch the fragment and put it inside my main app's MainActivity, from it.

So I decided to put my Fragments/Plug-ins into different apps and give all my plug-ins and main app the same user_id. This way all of them are in the same process, and even if they appear in the phone's Application Manager, only the main app is launchable and visible in the Application Browser (which is great).

But here's my problem... How do I get access to my plug-ins Fragments ?

I thought I could fetch some class through the PackageManager and use relfexion to use my fragment, but apparently you can't (or I didn't find how).

I considered binding Services together on each end (Application - Plug-in) but I have no guarantee that the services will bind together. Especially since each app have the same copy of the service, aka not the same Service.

Maybe by using a common .jar to make sure the Services are the same, and thus pass an instance of my Fragment to the main app (yes an instance would suffice).

Or make a CustomClassLoader (but then I might need advice on how to load classes from my other app, because I don't know how to do that...)

I've been running in circles in my head and on the net to find a solution...

To make things clear:

How do i fetch the classe (CustomClassLoader) or an instance (via binding or maybe sharedPreference or wiriting my instance in a file and read it in the main ?) of another app, considering they share the same user_id and thus are in the same process ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because apps share the same user_id this does not imply they are running in the same process. 
They may and propably have been started by the same process. 
Sharing resources amongst processes is commonly known as IPC.
AIDL , the android Interface Definition language  is a way for implementing IPC. 
Still this will not allow you retrieve objects from a different application directly but the possibility to invoke methods on remote objects.
But your problem description to me seems more like accessing objects of an jar at runtime in an application. This could be done via classloading.
So your app could retrieve a jar from a Server and load your fragments from it. The definitions of the fragments than would be runtime updateable if you define your fragments completely by code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Yes, i want to access the object more than the methods. You see, I made an abstract class which implements all my plug-in fragments and (somehow) they can run by themselves (considering you have an activity to add the fragment into).


So basically i would have to download the jar, load it with a (Custom?)ClassLoader. But then anyone would be able to fetch my jar file if they rooted their phone, and also i'd need to load the jar each time the app starts, no ?